# How to change like column for list layout Sharepoint

Tags: column, json, like

I implemented the like feature on a test column I have but I noticed the icon linked to the like is a little hart. I want to change that hart to a thumbsup or another icon. How can i do that?
I would assume this is done via column formatting with a json but I don't know how. Is there somewhere where i can find the standaard json for the like and just paste that with my changes or is there an easier way to do this?[image: column picture]

Answer (score 0):

You use the preferred icon as button, and bind to the rating mechanism.

Comment: Can you please alaborate on how to do that?